# postgres: dump partial tables between databases while maintaining sequences

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to copy select bits of several tables from one database to another while maintaining the sequences and schema. I first dump the schema using `pg_dump -s` but when it comes to copying the data I'm a little at a loss. Here's what I've tried so far:

`pg_dump -t <table1>` gives me sequences but includes the whole table

`copy (SELECT bits from table1)` gives me partial tables but doesn't keep the sequences up to date.

How can I keep my sequences up to date while only dumping parts of the tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing built-in will dump *part* of a table for you, so doing a `-s`/`--schema-only` dump and writing your own `COPY` statements is the way to go.

As noted in the [`pg_dump` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-OPTIONS), the `-t`/`--table` option will also take a sequence name. You can combine this with the `-a`/`--data-only` flag to output just the sequence's `setval(...)` command:

```sh
pg_dump --data-only -t <sequence_name>
```

Of course, if your sequences are associated with a `SERIAL` column, you usually don't know (or care) exactly what they're called. In that case, you can (probably) rely on the default `<table>_<column>_seq` naming convention to dump them all at once:

```sh
pg_dump --data-only -t *_seq
```

If you have non-standard sequence names, or if you're unfortunate enough to have a table name which ends in `_seq`, you might need to generate the sequence list programmatically. In `bash`, something like this would probably do it:

```sh
pg_dump --data-only -t $(psql -tAc "SELECT string_agg(oid::regclass::text, ',') FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'S'")
```

Comment: This is wonderful! It didn't occur to me to dump only the sequences. Thanks Nick!